# Android O background networking

Tags: java, android, networking, background-process, android-8.0-oreo

I was reading about background service limitation in Android 8 and from what I read it seems that you can't run your service in the background for a long time. This seems reasonable but because I use background service to keep connection to server - currently pooling new stuff, sending location and responses I am a bit confused. The responses are OK, I can respond only when interacting with the app, but the pooling new stuff is problematic because it needs to get an stuff from server and if something new come present the user with a notification to respond to it.

If I understand it correctly I can use JobScheduler to schedule some job every several seconds. I can basically schedule the pooling. For the background locations, well there are those restrictions so  only foreground service is an option to get updates in requested time.

I will be migrating to websockets and then the pooling is off, the connection to server will be persistent and the app will get updates from server, I was planing to do this in the background service so something would receive stuff from server everytime. However it seems I can't since Android 8. How would you solve this? Should I use foreground service for location and server connection? Or is there a better way to do background networking in an android app on android 8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few options for performing background work on Android O:

- Use JobScheduler. You already seem to have a good grasp on this one- the downside is that it is periodic, not persistent.
- Use GCM/FCM or a similar push service to push data to your app when it is relevant instead of constantly holding a connection to your server.
- [Use a foreground service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground). This will allow you to continue performing your background work without your app being in the foreground, but will put a notification in the status bar to inform your user that you are doing that work.

Before you select one of these methods, you should take a moment to step back and look at the data that you need from your server and determine *why* you need a persistent connection and whether the first or second options might be sufficient.

If you absolutely need a persistent connection to your server, the last option is your best option. The idea behind the changes in O is to still allow background work such as what you are describing, but to make it painfully obvious to the user that your app is doing so. That way if they don't think your data is as important as you do, they can take action.